# Where is the documentation for my compiler located?

Tags: linux, compiler

## Background

On page 5 of [C++ Primer 5th edition](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/c-primer-fifth/9780133053043/), Exercise 1.1 asks this question:

> Review the documentation for you compiler and determine what file naming convention is uses. Compile and run the main program from page 2.

I've never had to knowingly go in depth into my compiler information before and am wholly unaware as to where this is normally stored.  This prompted me to ask the question...

## Question

Where is the documentation for my machine's compiler located?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation would usually be in manpages and `/usr/share/doc`. Usually, a symlink called `cc` points to the specific default compiler installed, so you should be able to determine which compiler is the default for your system using `man cc`. Then look online or in `/usr/share/docs` for the complete documentation.

Answer (score 0):

On Unix systems (and lookalikes) the main documentation should be available as e.g. `man cc` (or whatever your compiler is called). That will give you an overview of use, including relevant command line switches. This is Unix custom, but some installation scrimping on disk space might not have manuals on line (but the few dozen MiB saved won't be worth the hassle nowadays).

More detailed documentation (for example, a compiler claiming conformance to an ISO standard should have documentation detailing how it handles various implementation dependencies, others may handle extensions of the language) might also be on line, or on paper only, or available from the vendor somehow. There are no general rules, sorry.

Perhaps you should narrow your question to the compiler(s) and environments of interest, and the exact point of interest.

For your specific question, common conventions for C++ source files are `*.C`, `*.cc`, `*.cpp`; with header files called `*.hh`, `*.hpp`, or just plain `*.h` (like C). As this is managed by `#include` lines written by the programmer, it is more or less arbitrary (and the current standard uses file names without extension for standard headers). Many C++ compilers will take files called  `*.c` as plain C, others you can give arbitrary file names and tell about contents with command line switches.

File names may make a difference if you use some form of IDE (Integrated Development Environment), it might insist on some specific naming convention. Again, no blanket statement is possible, find and check it's documentation (probably under some help function on line).